# Regular expression to extract words before a slash

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract the two words FIRST and SECOND from the phrase below, i've tried with this regex, to get the word before the slash but it doesn't work : / btw it's on python:

```
 import re 

    data = "12341    O:EXAMPLE (FIRST:/xxxxxx) R:SECOND/xxxxx id:1234"
    data2 = "12341    O:EXAMPLE:FIRST2:/xxxxxx) R:SECOND2/xxxxx id:1234"

    result = re.findall(r'[/]*',data)
    result2 = re.findall(r'[/]*',data2)
    print result,result2
```

Comment: You are matching nothing but `/` slashes in your expression.

Comment: What about the colon?

Comment: You need to read up on regular expressions. You are searching for 0 or more `/` characters.

Comment: Also there is no need for the character set `[/]*` to hold a single character, `/*` should suffice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
result = re.findall(r'\w+:?(?=/)',data)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\w+   # Match one or more alphanumeric characters
:?    # Match an optional colon
(?=/) # Assert that the next character is a slash
```

If you don't want the colon to be part of the match (your question is unclear on this), put the optional colon into the lookahead assertion:

```
result = re.findall(r'\w+(?=:?/)',data)
```

Comment: @SkivlageLatif: Use the second version.